# Does mongoose query need to be cached?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am developing a very simple blog in Node.js. But I am very curious about query caching in mongoose.

Does mongoose handles cache? What to do if its not inbuilt in mongoose?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

simple answer is no but you can use caching libraries my favorite is [cacheman](https://github.com/cayasso/cacheman). but you can try other according to you need like [mongoose-cachebox](https://github.com/cayasso/mongoose-cachebox)

cacheman is Small and efficient cache provider for Node.JS with In-memory, File, Redis and MongoDB engines.

links:

https://github.com/cayasso/cacheman

https://github.com/cayasso/mongoose-cachebox